# How can I get my youtube background video to load when navigating between pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, youtube-api

Background video loads properly and autoplays etc. when the page is first loaded (and when refreshed) but when navigating to the page via the navbar links the video wont load.

Site is using Ruby on Rails if that makes any difference.

I suspect my issue is somewhere in the js but I'm new to this and haven't been able to sort out what isn't triggering

Script for the video:

// Video Script //

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
// Inserts YouTube JS code into the page.
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;

// onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() is called when the IFrame API is ready to go.
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '360',
        width: '640',
        videoId: '7copSLUofm8',
        playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'rel': 0, 'enablejsapi':1, 'wmode' : 'transparent'},
        events : {
            'onReady' : pkOnPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange' : pkOnPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

function pkOnPlayerStateChange(e) {
    var frm = $(e.target.getIframe());
    if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        if ('player' === frm.attr('id')) {
            player.playVideo();
        }
    }
    if (e.data === YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
        if ('player' === frm.attr('id')) {
            e.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
        }
    }
}
function pkOnPlayerReady(e) {
    player.mute();
    e.target.setPlaybackQuality('hd720');
}

//Load a youtube pixel
var pkEnableYoutube = function() {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { return deferred.resolve(); };
    img.onerror = function() { return deferred.reject(); };
    img.src = "https://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/pixel-vfl3z5WfW.gif?"+ new Date().getTime();
    return deferred.promise();
};

//When the video starts to load, set a timer for the video wrap to fade in
jQuery(function($){
    $.when(pkEnableYoutube()).done(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.video_wrap').fadeIn();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a textbook Turbolinks issue. I'm guessing you can solve it by wrapping your call in `jQuery.on('turbolinks:load', callback)` instead of [`jQuery.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).  https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events

Comment: Not sure exactly how to fix the turbolinks issue with the youtube API, is there a way for me to change the youtube js that's being linked?

The easiest work around I found was just to embed the Youtube video rather than use the api code...is there a reason why I shouldn't do that? Are there potential load time issues using the embed?

Comment: "is there a reason why I shouldn't do that?" - yes and no. Iframes come with a host of problems on their own like that they don't work well with responsive layouts.